# Moving all the tables in a Word document to the end of the document

Tags: arrays, vba, indexing, dynamic, static

I want to move all the tables to the end of the document, just in order to, in a separate session, deal with all the other non-table (ordinary) paragraphs first. This is the code I (eventually) came up with:

```
Dim iCounter As Integer

For iCounter = 1 To ThisDocument.Tables.Count
    ThisDocument.Tables(1).Range.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.EndKey (wdStory)
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Paste
Next iCounter
```

It already worked. However, I want to know: Why did I always have to operate the 1st table, instead of the 1st, 2nd... and so on to the last? What is the general term or the general concept for this "constantly changing indexes" or "unchanging-where-it-is-supposed-to-change" phenomenon? Why an ordinary loop such as the following would not work?

```
for each oTable in ThisDocument.Tables
    oTable.Range.Cut
    Selection.EndKey (wdStory)
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Paste
DoEvents
next oTable
```

The above solution, a seemingly normal loop, turns out incorrent and ends up nonstop running. I had to force-close the Word window. And:

```
Dim iCounter as Integer

For iCounter = 1 To ThisDocument.Tables.Count
    ThisDocument.Tables(iCounter).Range.Cut
    Selection.EndKey (wdStory)
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Paste
Next iCounter
```

The above solution, another seemingly normal loop, upon trial run, outputs a "semi-finished" product, i.e., it moves some, instead of all, of the tables.

Comment: Is it that the index goes by position so when you move the first the next table becomes the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your original question posed by your first working example - why always select `Table(1)`? When you cut the table out and put it at the end of the document, what was then `Table(1)` becomes `Table(n)` and `Table(2)` now becomes `Table(1)`. But it works, because you are not changing the overall count of the tables, so that loop iterates exactly `n` times.

In your second example, you are deleting an object from a collection while iterating through the collection. Because you are then placing that object at the end of the collection, the iteration never reaches the end. *Cardinal rule: never delete or re-order anything while in a `For-Each` loop!*.

Your third example is similar: You are removing something from a selection and then placing it at the end of the selection - weird behaviour. In this case, you are also incrementing the table number. So, if `Table(1)` moves to the end, and `Table(2)` becomes `Table(1)`, when you increment the `icounter` to `2`, you are really working on what was originally `Table(3)` [now `Table(2)`] and the new `Table(1)` [was `Table(2)`] is untouched.

The easiest way to avoid this confusion when you know you are cutting something from a collection or list is to work backwards. Then you can avoid the subtle coding nuance of `(1)` instead of `(iCounter)`.

```
Dim iCounter as Integer
Dim NumLoops as Long

NumLoops = ThisDocument.Tables.Count 
' NumLoops is not important in this example, but 
' when you delete (not move) a table you also change the overall count.

For iCounter = NumLoops To 1 Step -1    
    ThisDocument.Tables(iCounter).Range.Cut
    Selection.EndKey (wdStory)
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Paste
Next iCounter
```